# How to start android to use Openstreet Map offline?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I can't find relevant answer in the internet.
I want to use Openstreet Map offline as getting the map inside the sdcard and develop for Android app.
I can't find step by step guide how to save into sdcard. Then develop offline map.
Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at osmdroid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a good question, but I will try to answer:

As @scai says, there is the #osmdroid toolbox that adds a widget to display OSM map tiles. This rendered tiles can be cached or downloaded from the OSM servers (respect TUP) and shared offline.

There are also other solutions to realize it https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

But please keep in mind, that it's usually not that easy:

- maps get outdated and you wan't to update them at client side
- map servers are shared goods and high speed bulk download is a shame
- quickly your users will request geocoding, routing and all the features of Google Maps
- quickly you want tot display more complex information on top of your widget

So I encourage you to think about what needs to be done first (also for further versions) and then pick the right toolbox :)